# Looking for Dart documentation on observables

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, observable

I am looking for documentation, but I don't know what term I should be searching with.
I have an observable:

```
@observable String inputName66='';
```

and (from various cuts and pastes from other users' codes!), this function:

```
 void inputName66Changed(Event e, var newValue, var Target) {
```

So the "inputName66Changed" is an "expected" function, expected by Dart (Polymer?) by extending the observable name by adding "Changed".

Where can I find the documentation for these "name extensions" please? And what other extensions are available?  I assume they're generated by the Observe class, but I don't see it.

Thanks in advance
Steve

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the Polymer lifeCycle methods. See https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#lifecyclemethods (`attributeChanged`)